# YouTube API PHP V3: Upload with RecordingDetails (Google API Client V2)

Tags: php, youtube

Every Youtube Upload Call fails, as soon as "RecordingDetails" are included.

The following simple Call (Extract):

```
$rc=new \Google_Service_YouTube_VideoRecordingDetails();
$rc->setRecordingDate('2016-08-02T21:17:00.000Z');
$video->setRecordingDetails($rc);
```

fails.
I also tried with a Location:

```
$rc=new \Google_Service_YouTube_VideoRecordingDetails();
$ld=new \Google_Service_YouTube_GeoPoint();
$ld->setLatitude(36.527294814546);
$ld->setLongitude(128.5400390625);
$rc->setLocation($ld);
$video->setRecordingDetails($rc);
```

The same Error occurs.
Additionally, the Error Message is not really helpfull :)

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.part",
    "reason": "unexpectedPart",
    "message": "{0}",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "part"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "{0}"
 }
}
```

Did anyone already mentioned to upload a Video with Api V3 and Google Client V2 and a RecordingDetail?

If someone is interested, here is how the RecordingDetails Object looks like:

```
Google_Service_YouTube_VideoRecordingDetails Object
(
    [locationType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_GeoPoint
    [locationDataType:protected] => 
    [locationDescription] => 
    [recordingDate] => 2016-08-02T21:17:00.000Z
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [location] => Google_Service_YouTube_GeoPoint Object
        (
            [altitude] => 
            [latitude] => 36.527294814546
            [longitude] => 128.5400390625
            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Thanks,
Christoph

Answer (score 3):

Change this

```
$youtube->videos->insert('status,snippet', $video);
```

To this

```
$youtube->videos->insert('status,snippet,recordingDetails', $video);
```

Swap insert for update if needed.